# Error when importing vector data into Earth Engine via asset manager

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, google-earth-engine, vector

I am trying to import the shapefile of my country into the Earth Engine asset manager in order to perform some analysis, but I keep getting the error message below on every attempt after the task runs for just a few seconds. How can I possibly solve this?

I earlier imported a previous shapefile and it was ok, though that was from another region of the world. I can display my shapefile in my ArcGIS application and it works well without projection error, so this is baffling and confusing for me.

```
Error: Projection exception. Ensure the projection is specified correctly and 
  the coordinates are within its valid area.
Detailed error: Unable to transform edge (582813.687498, 570842.062498 to 
  582813.688795, 570842.063945) from EPSG:4326 PLANAR to EPSG:4326..
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. 
I suggest tagging Earth Engine.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, I re-projected the shapefile in ArcGIS pro to WGS_1954 and then uploaded to GEE.